# Give 6 topological spaces satisfying this

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

As an excercise, I have to give 6 compact, Hausdorff and path connected topological spaces ${Z_k}_{k=1}^6$ such that pairwise are not homotopic and satisfying that $|\pi_1 (Z_k) | \leq 5$.

My question is, is it fine to take $Z_k = {\Bbb{P} \Bbb{R}}^{k+1}$ ? They are compact, Hausdorff and path connected, but I do not know how to justify that they are pairwise not homotopic

Comment: If you know about singular homology, then they are not homotopy equivalent because they have different singular homology groups. If you have not learned about singular homology, I'd suggest a different approach. Try to find $Z_k$ so that $|\pi_1(Z_k)| = k - 1$; then it follows from the homotopy invariance of the fundamental group that the $Z_k$ are not homotopy equivalent.